# How to hide passed request parameters from the user?

Tags: jsp, http, url, parameters

In my jsp page I have a link:

```
<a href="adminView.do?profile=all">Clear</a>
```

If I click the link in the browser address bar I can see:

```
 adminView.do?profile=all
```

instead of

```
adminView.do
```

How to hide passed request parameters from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order hide the parameters you must use a form and post the data.  You can't just use an `<a>` tag.  You can still pull off the look you are going for with a form.  Just put the form tags around your anchor tag:

```
<form id="postRequest" action="adminView.do" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="profile" value="all"/>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('postRequest').submit()">Clear</a>
</form>
```

Here is a [helpful link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) about sending and retrieving form data.

And here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gw1tzxx1/) to show what the URL looks like when submitting a form using post vs get.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide parameters from users, you will have to use post request. In your href call a method to generate post request and then send it.